# Is there any registry of active 24/7 animal video feeds (from public IP-like cameras)?

Tags: data-request, real-time, animals, video

I am developing a IP-ish surveillance-like animals behaviour analyzing solution. I have some private video streams, but to check method robustness I need to be able to check on other animal types\locations\light conditions. So I wonder if there is some "registry" or list of publicly available 24\7 animal video stream links (say of some zoos)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No registry that I am aware of, but some government sites do post all of the webcams within their agency/department/etc., like [NPS Air Quality Web Cameras](https://www.nature.nps.gov/air/webcams/index.cfm).
I keep a lists of some webcams, here are the ones that have animals.

[EarthCam Live Webcam Network](https://www.earthcam.com/)  has over [500 Search Results for "Animals and Zoos"](http://www.earthcam.com/search/adv_search.php?cat[]=ANI) as well as an [Animal Cams section](http://www.earthcam.com/events/animalcams/).
[Eagle Cam @ Berry College, GA](http://www.berry.edu/eaglecam/)
[FWS Eagle Cam](https://nctc.fws.gov/topic/eagle-cam/)
[DC Eagle Cam](http://www.dceaglecam.org/)
[Animal Planet Live](http://www.animalplanet.com/video-topics/aplive/)
[San Diego Zoo](http://kids.sandiegozoo.org/animal-cams-videos)
[Kelp Forest Cam - Channel Island National Park](http://explore.org/live-cams/player/channel-islands-national-park-anacapa-ocean)
[Under Water Scuba Cam - Channel Island National Park](http://explore.org/live-cams/player/channel-islands-national-park-live-adventures)
[Bear Cam - Brooks Falls](http://explore.org/live-cams/player/brown-bear-salmon-cam-brooks-falls)
[Puffin Burrow Cam](http://explore.org/live-cams/player/puffin-burrow-cam)
[Farallon Islands Live Webcam](http://www.calacademy.org/webcams/farallones/)
[Farm Sanctuary - Pig Pasture](https://explore.org/live-cams/player/pig-pasture-farm-sanctuary)
[Shark Lagoon Cam](http://www.calacademy.org/explore-science/shark-lagoon-cam)
[Live Penguins Cam](http://www.calacademy.org/explore-science/live-penguin-cams)
[Penguin Cam](https://www.kansascityzoo.org/animal-cams/penguin-cam/)
[Phillipine Coral Reef Cam](http://www.calacademy.org/explore-science/philippine-coral-reef-cam)
[Wolf Cams](http://www.wolf.org/meet-our-wolves/wolfcams/)
[International Wolf Center Exhibit Pack Live Stream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PB6PdAwz4as)
[Panda Cam - San Diego](http://zoo.sandiegozoo.org/cams/panda-cam)
[Panda Cam - Atlanta](http://zooatlanta.org/panda-cam/)
[Panda Cam - National Zoo](https://nationalzoo.si.edu/webcams/panda-cam)
[Live Safari Cams](http://www.africam.com/wildlife/)
[Video Streams Broadcasing Live from the National Aquarium](https://aqua.org/webcams)
[Elephant Cam - National Zoo](https://nationalzoo.si.edu/webcams/elephants)
[Lion Cam - National Zoo](https://nationalzoo.si.edu/webcams/lion-cam)

Note: Explore.org has a lot of webcams of animal life, but make sure you are watching the live feed vs. the highlights reel from the previous season that they run during hibernation season.